# Oblivious Decision Making

Tags: multiparty-computation, mixnets

Suppose there is a ciphertext $C_1$ that hides message $m_1$ using a distributed additively homomorphic public key.  I would like the holders of the key to run a protocol where if $m_1 = 0$, then it will return a ciphertext of $0$, but if $m_1 \neq 0$, then it will return a ciphertext of $1$.  However, I would like this done without the key holders knowing whether $m_1 = 0$.  I am assuming that there are not enough key holders that refuse to improperly decrypt the $C_1$

My instinct is to use some kind mix network using a Plaintext Equality Test.  However, the result of the PET (true or false) would allow the key holders and any external verifier to know whether $m_1 = 0$.

Is there a known mechanism to allow the key holders to return a ciphertext with the correct value without it being made known which path was taken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most natural option would be the following:

- Let the parties run threshold decryption to obtain additive shares of the plaintext $m_1$
- Run an MPC protocol that takes as input shares of $m_1$ and outputs shares of the equality test $[m_1 = _? 0]$. For example, in the two-party setting, you can use [my paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/544.pdf) (which is more or less still the state of the art, depending on your exact context -- size of $m_1$, time for preprocessing, number of executions, etc). There are also solutions in the $n$-party setting, the introduction of my paper should indicate what was the state of the art in 2016, but I'm not sure what would be the best solution now.
- Convert back the shares of the output into an encryption of the output, the usual way: everyone encrypts their shares, broadcasts the ciphertexts, and the encrypted shares are homomorphically summed to recover the encrypted result.

In the two-party setting, there are very efficient equality tests (the one from my paper, but also others which are better if preprocessing is cheap, like [this one](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1392)), so this should overall work very well. I expect it to be more costly in the $n$-party setting with $n>2$, but you should search a bit the literature to know for sure!

*EDIT for clarification:*

The paper just assume that two parties have $x$ and $y$, and want to test whether $x = y$. If you have a threshold encryption scheme where the plaintext space is $\mathbb{Z}_n$, after threshold decryption, the parties have respective shares $m_1, m_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ (seen as integers between $0$ and $n-1$) of the plaintext $m$. Then, testing whether $m=0 \bmod n$ is equivalent to testing whether $m_1 + m_2 = n$, i.e. testing whether $m_1 = n-m_2$. Hence, $P_1$ sets $x=m_1$, $P_2$ sets $y = n-m*2$, and the two parties run an equality test, as in my paper.

In the end, the parties have shares *mod 2* of the result: that is, $b_1, b_2$ such that $b_1 \oplus b_2 = [m =_? 0]$, where $\oplus$ is the XOR. Then, the parties can easily construct an encryption of $[m =_? 0]$ with their additively homomorphic encryption scheme, using the identity $b_1 \oplus b_2 = b_1 + b_2 - 2b_1b_2$: $P_1$ sends a random encryption of $b_1$, and $P_2$ homomorphically compute an encryption of $b_1(1-2b_2) + b_2 = b_1 \oplus b_2 = [m=_? 0]$ (and rerandomizes it).

Comment: Thanks for responding. From what I understood, your paper requires a bit-wise encrypted cipher. Unfortunately, in my larger setting, the ciphertext has gone through a large number of homomorphic operations that make determining a bitwise form of it difficult without decrypting it, which would defeat the purpose.  Running these operations with bitwise ciphertexts would be prohibitively expensive.

Comment: No, my paper does not require this at all, it operates on shares over an integer ring, precisely what you get by doing distributed description of a standard additively homomorphic scheme, e.g. Paillier or something similar. I never assume any bitwise sharing and I don't think I mention anything about this setting in the paper.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood a part where you were talking about shares of size Z_2.

Comment: I wanted to write a comment to clarify exactly how to solve your problem using an equality test in the two-party setting, but it ended up being a bit long for the comment section, so I edited my answer. Feel free to ask if you need further clarification!

Comment: So the idea is that the multiple parties check to see if m_1 = n - m_2, and they get bits that can be combined with XOR to get an answer.  A couple questions:  I thought homomorphic XOR only existed in subgroups of size 2 and that a bitwise XOR required a bitwise representation of the ciphertext.

Comment: I will say I didn't fully follow your PET protocol, and I would love to understand it.  But your approach of splitting it in to shares then processing it internally between the parties gave me a solution that will work in my context.  Thanks!

Comment: (Answering your second to last comment) see the EDIT to my answer: I explain how the parties can compute the XOR on their ciphertexts, using only standard mod n homomorphic operations (additions, multiplications by a constant) plus some interaction. The key trick is that x XOR y is the same as x + y - 2*x*y mod n for any large modulus n, when x and y are bits.

Comment: So it is.  I'm kicking myself for not knowing that, I must have known it at some point.